# Recursive reference in prolog

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

I meet some problem when I try to implement

```
friends(mia, ellen).
friends(mia, lucy).
friends(X,Y) :-
  friends(X,Z),
  friends(Y,Z).
```

and when i ask `?- friends(mia, X).`, it run out of local stack.

Then I add

```
friends(ellen, mia) friends(lucy, mia)
```

I ask  `?- friends(mia, X).` ,it keeps replying `X = mia`.

I can't understand, why it is recursive?

Comment: *Clauses of `friends/2` are not together in the source-file* means that between definitions of `friends/2` clauses you've defined other clauses. Note that `friends(mia, ellen) friends(mia, lucy).` isn't valid syntax. So I assume what you're showing isn't really what your code looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, two assumptions:

- the actual code you wanted to write is the following one, with appropriate dots:

  ```
  friends(mia,ellen).
  friends(mia,lucy).
  friends(X,Y) :- 
     friends(X,Z),
     friends(Z,Y).
  ```
- transivity holds: friends of friends are my friends too (I would rather model friendship as a distance: "A is near B" and "B is near C" does not necessarly imply "A is near C"). [repeat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29929513/124319) is right about figuring out first what you want to model.

Now, let's see why we go into infinite recursion.

## Step-by-step

So, what happens when we ask: `friends(mia,X)` ?

1. First clause gives `Y=ellen` (you ask for more solutions)
2. Second clause gives `Y=lucy` (you ask again for more solutions)
3. Stack overflow !

#### Let's detail the third clause:

1. I want to know if `friends(mia,Y)` holds for some variable `Y`.
2. Is there a variable `Z` such that `friends(mia,Z)` holds ?

   *Notice that apart from a renaming from `Y` to `Z`, we are asking the same question as step 1 above?* **This smells like infinite recursion**, but let's see...
3. We try the first two clauses of `friends`, but then we fail because there is no `friends(ellen,Y)` nor `friends(lucy,Y)`, so...
4. We call the third clause in order to find if there is a transitive friendship, and we are back to step 1 without having progressed any further => infinite recursion.

This problem is analogous to infinite [Left recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion) in context-free grammars.

## A fix

Have two predicates:

1. `known_friends/2`, which gives direct relationships.
2. `friends/2`, which also encodes transitivity

   ```
   known_friends(mia,ellen).
   known_friends(mia,lucy).

   friends(X,Y) :- known_friends(X,Y).
   friends(X,Y) :- known_friends(X,Z), friends(Z,Y).
   ```

Now, when we ask `friends(mia,X)`, `friends/2` gives the same answer as the two clauses of `known_friends/2`, but does not find any answer for the transitive clause: the difference here is that `known_friends` will make a little progress, namely find a known friend of `mia` (without recursion), and try to find (recursively) if that friend is a friend of some other people.

## Friends' friends

If we add `known_friends(ellen, bishop)` <sup>:-)</sup> then `friends` will also find `Y=bishop`, because:

- `known_friends(mia,ellen)` holds, and
- `friends(ellen,bishop)` is found recursively.

## Circularity

If you add cyclic dependencies in the friendship graph (in `known_friends`), then you *will* have an infinite traversal of this graph with `friends`. Before you can fix that, you have to consider the following questions:

- Does `friends(X,Y) <=> friends(Y,X)` hold for all `(X,Y)` ?
- What about `friends(X,X)`, for all `X` ?

Then, you should keep a set of all seen people when evaluating `friends` in order to detect when you are looping through `known_friends`, while taking into account the above properties. This should not be too difficult too implement, if you want to try.

Comment: Thank you, now I know why it run out of stack. It is explicit and helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This clause of `friends/2` is flawed:

```
friends(X,Y) :- friends(X,Z),friends(Y,Z).
```

Translate that into English: "If `X` and `Y` have a mutual friend `Z`, then `X` and `Y` are friends."

Or, let's specialize, let `X` be "me", let `Y` be my neighbour "FooBert", and let `Z` be "you": So if I am your friend and FooBert is your friend... does that make me and FooBert friends? I don't think so, I hate that guy---he always slams the door when he gets home. :)

I suggest you consider the algebraic properties that the relation `friends/2` *should* have, the ones it *may* have, and ones it *should not* have. What about reflexivity, symmetry, anti-symmetry, transitivity?

Comment: hum.. I just study prolog several hours. I was wondering if someone has ever used it to proof something in geometry, like if line a parallel with line b, line b parallel with line c , then line a parallel with line c.